# Как отследить открытие файла, и сделать что-то перед его непосредственным открытием?

Tags: c#, файлы

Вообщем пишу программу на C#, надо чтобы при открытии пользователем любого файла(вне программы), сначала запускалась моя проверка на доступ, а потом файл открывался или нет.
Вопрос в том : каким методом или способом можно отследить открытие так, чтобы проверка сработала перед открытием?
Искал подобное, но что-то не нашел. Заранее, благодарю.

Comment: Я правильно понял, что вы хотите отслеживать вашей программой попытку открытия пользователем любого файла в файловой системе?

Answer (score 7):

С такой постановкой - нужен драйвер ядра, который встанет перед файловой системой. Только на C# его сделать не получится.

Так что ответ - никак.

Answer (score -1):

> С такой постановкой - нужен драйвер ядра
>   Так что ответ - никак.

Вокруг любого "никак" есть обходной путь. Свой драйвер создавать не обязательно, так как можно воспользоваться готовым решением, например, в FileMon (бесплатная утилита для 32-битных и 64-разрядных операционных систем Microsoft Windows, разработанная Sysinternals).
А как из программы на C# воспользоваться решением в FileMon - это уже другой вопрос, примерно такой: Как с помощью хуков перехватить вывод в окне сторонней программы?

Comment: FileMon позволяет получить информацию об открытии файла уже **после** его открытия. А требуется тут - ловить команду открытия файла перед открытием, да еще и с возможностью решать допускать открытие файла или нет.